# How do I get a selection from the output of a grep

Tags: ruby, regex, shell, replace

I have the following text in a file :

```
<img id="img_1" style="display: none" src="Logs/P2P2014-04-10_14-24-49.txt"/></span></div></div><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = "Finished in <strong>1m31.846s seconds</strong>";</script><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('totals').innerHTML = "1
```

What I want to do is obtain the stuff after the src i.e. `Logs/P2P2014-04-10_14-24-49.txt`. I tried the following and put it into a variable in ruby or so :

I tried doing :

```
text = `grep 'Logs\/.*txt\"'`
```

But that returns the entire damn line instead of only the text. How do I get this done?

Comment: The accept answer is not really correct, thinking if there are several `Logs` or `txt` in same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
text=$(grep -o 'Logs\/.*txt\"')
```

It should return only matching part of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/), see how easy to solve the problem :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-html
<img id="img_1" style="display: none" src="Logs/P2P2014-04-10_14-24-49.txt"/></span></div></div>
html

doc.at('#img_1')['src'] # => "Logs/P2P2014-04-10_14-24-49.txt"
```

Read [tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) to understand and learn Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed -n 's/.*src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' file
```

Using gnu grep if support -P option

```
grep -Po '(?<=src=")[^"]*' file
```